# Is there a spec document for CCTray?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, travis-ci, cctray, ccmenu

I'm trying to build a CCTray/CCMenu clone in Electron and want to know if there's a spec document for parsing the XML document? I can get much of it from checking my [Travis version](https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/riggerthegeek.xml), but I'd like to know the actual spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Our source code](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-api/blob/8fac307ad258becd0a1b2c44c1b257232d7d65b0/lib/travis/api/app/responders/xml.rb#L5) sadly has outdated info. A quick search reveals https://github.com/erikdoe/ccmenu/wiki/Multiple-Project-Summary-Reporting-Standard, which claims to have resurrected the "lost" standard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the spec for CCTray is available from here: https://cctray.org/v1/